# How to find out my user id?

Tags: support, add-on, user-accounts

Ok so I got the Stack Overflow addon for Firefox (and the Gnome Panel Applet) and I just realised my UserID is not the same as Username, its a numerical value. How can I find this to make sure I have the correct stats?

The way I know it is a numerical value

1. Open Prefrences of AskUbuntu Firefox Addon
2. Look at the User ID field, there is a one.
3. Try typing in letters... It won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on your profile and look at the URL: meta.askubuntu.com/users/**2733**/russjr08

Your user ID is **2733**.

Comment: Thank You, I have marked this answer as the answer and voted up! This is just what I was looking for!